# Is there a limit to the number of cases that can be bulk uploaded at a time?

Tags: commcare

Is there a limit to the number of cases that can be bulk uploaded at a time?

Please advice.

Answer (score 1):

There's no hard limit, but it gets more and more painful as the number gets bigger.  Its generally advised to upload no more than 5,000 - 10,000 at a time.